# build-impl.xml:1031: The module has not been deployed

Tags: java, tomcat, web, netbeans-7

I have been working on a Java web application and i am  using *SmartGwt* on *Netbeans 7.3* and out of a sudden I encountered this problem. I tried cleaning the `build-impl.xml` then restarting the IDE and I should say I have fairly low knowledge on this. Can someone please tell me why it is giving an error and how I can fix that?

The error message says :

```
nbproject/build-impl.xml:1031: The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details. 
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Note: i am using *Tomcat 7.0.34*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

may its so late but the response useful for others so : 
Sometimes, when you don't specify a server or servlet container at the 
creation of the project, *NetBeans* fails to create a `context.xml` file.

1. In your project under Web Pages, create a folder called `META-INF`.

Do this by right mouse button clicking on Web pages, and select:

`New->Other->Other->File Folder`

Name the folder `META-INF`. Case is important, even on Windows.

1. Create a file called `context.xml` in the `META-INF` folder.

Do this by right mouse button clicking on the new `META-INF` folder, and 
select:

`New->Other->XML->XML` Document

Name it context (NetBeans adds the `.xml`) 
Select Well-formed Document 
Press Finish

1. Edit the new document (`context.xml`), and add the following:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/app-name"/>
   ```

Replace app-name with the name of your application.

Now your in-place deployment should work. If not, make sure that the 
file can be read by everyone.

The `context.xml` file is specific to Tomcat. For more information about 
that file, see the Tomcat documentation at `tomcat.apache.org`.

Comment: i have same problem but with the glassfish can i use this solution?

Comment: Yes. @Tony. You can use it. If you want to switch from Tomcat to Glassfish server,Right click to your project name in project explorer. Go to properties-> categories-> select run option. And change the server.

Comment: This answer is still relevant!

Answer (score 6):

Start your IDE with administrative privilege( Windows: right click and run as admin), so that it has read write access to tomact folder for deployment. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Take a look at the server logs!**

I had been with this for hours. The awful Tomcat servlet is not very helpful neither but if you can see the stacktrace that should be enough.

For instance, I read the following error message there:

[image: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [DetailsServlet] and [AddToCart] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/carrito] which is not permitted]

As you can see, the message was pretty clear and easy to fix :-)

Comment: it worked for me. I also had same issue same url pattern mapping for two servlets

Comment: **"Take a look at the server logs!"** It would be useful if the error message said where the server logs are, or what server.

Answer (score 2):

- Check if there any other instance of the server is running already
- Check if the port that will be used by the server is free.

Answer (score 1):

If you add jars in tomcat's lib folder you can see this error

Answer (score 0):

- Close Netbeans.
- Delete all libraries in the folder "yourprojectfolder"\build\web\WEB-INF\lib
- Open Netbeans.
- Clean and Build project.
- Deploy project.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reason for this error is due to permission not granted to all users. so remove this error, follow the following steps :
1) Go to the **C:/Programme Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0**
2) Right click on the **Tomcat 7.0** folder and click on **properties**.
3) go to **Security** Tab.
4) Select the User and click on **Edit**... button
5) Grant all the permission to the user and click on **apply** and **ok**.
Refresh the system and now try. I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

if you still getting this error try this.

1. Go to Netbeans services
2. Remove Apache Tomcat.
3. Add Apache Tomcat again.
4. Build Project.
5. Deploy Project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in my case , it said that the 8080 port is in use , so I change the server port of Tomcat to 8081 and it works

Answer (score -1):

Check whether you placed the  within the .. or outside the ...
If you placed it outside the server tag , and if you try to access the init-parameter then it will give error.