# C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1108: The module has not been deployed

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I am new to tiles in Struts2 framework. For more information I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 and Tomcat 8.0.15

and I am getting this error

> C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1108:
>   The module has not been deployed.

before this questioning the question I searched in web.. I validated xml
and I get..

> XML validation started. Checking
>   file:/C:/Users/HP/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication2/web/WEB-INF/tiles.xml...
>   Referenced entity at
>   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd". tiles.apache.org
>   [2]  XML validation finished.

now what to do i am confused..

any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: sir , i just copy from web https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-tiles-example-1.html and i am facing the above mention error.

Comment: have you tried the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400810/build-impl-xml1031-the-module-has-not-been-deployed

Comment: yes i did it..but same error was reflecting

Comment: i tried following step :- i validate the xml , created context.xml, plugged in all necceseay  jar files for tiles..but then also i m getting error please go through it ...

C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1108: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 7 seconds)

Comment: after creating context.xml and validating it ...i got this issue ........XML validation started.
Checking file:/C:/Users/HP/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication2/web/META-INF/context.xml...
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Context'. [2] 
XML validation finished.

Comment: @sufiyanali You don't need this file to deploy on the server. Try better tutorial.