# Netbeans IDE 8.1: The module has not been deployed

Tags: java, apache, netbeans-8

I'm using Netbeans 8.1 with Apache 1.7.1. I've been working on the project for more than a year now, on and off. It's been working perfectly more or less. The majority of project libs are inside server lib folder.

All of a sudden it is decided to remove rich faces libs from the server on Production and include them inside of the project - not my idea, but here we are. So I remove the libs from server on my machine, include them in project libraries, and the aforementioned error appears just like that:

```
 ...\build-impl.xml:1066: The module has not been deployed. 
See the server log for details.
```

But the server log is clean and without errors.

I tried restarting server, Netbeans, pc and whatnot, but to no avail. I decided to take a step back: remove libs from project, copy them back to sever. But the problem remains.

I've tried solutions from at least three topics here: disabling network, cleaning Netbeans cache, ending Java task and others, but the problem still remains. Is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: Hmm ;-/ Not an easy problem to help with - when there is no actually that many information available. I would just suggest **1.** Check - are you sure that you are opening the correct serer log file . **2.** Check this post [out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400810/build-impl-xml1031-the-module-has-not-been-deployed)  3. Set up new environment (I hope you kept backup of an old one) and try running there ... good luck, man!

Comment: I tried to provide as much info as I thought was needed, so if there is anything else that could help, I'd gladly provide. 1. Checked, it's the server in question. 2. Saw this topic as well, checked the context.xml, everything is in place. As I said the project was completely operational prior to libraries removal. 3. What exactly do you mean by new environment?

Comment: Supposing that no code was damaged during removal of libraries from the server and addition to the project - same project should be able to run in a new environment a) say if  you install a new instance of Apache in the same NetBeans and set it up b) or if you run it in a newly set up netbeans (say on another pc).  If it works, then there could be some leftovers in apache or netbeans that are preventing the project from deploying... I hope someone will give you a better advice ... however that is what I would do - if nothing else proved to work.

Comment: Actually someone already tried removing libraries on production server - the project stopped working as expected. But after adding them back in the project resumed stable operation. Does that count as testing in another environment?

Comment: Not exactly - production has only the binary code. While on your local machine I assume you do `build` first (from the source code) and then deploy. If you are sure that nothing in your source code and configuration files was altered - than it could count as same. But, can you be sure?  However, most probably something went wrong during deployment / underemployment (Netbeans / Apache), so you could either find what went wrong (with a little bit of luck), or set up a clean environment that will work for you.

Comment: I took a clean new apache distributive, copied my libs and settings from my old one, and it worked. Although this does feel kinda random. But thanks for the idea :)

Comment: Welcome ;-)  glad that it worked.